# Periods in the name of c# dynamic ExpandoObjects?

Tags: c#, expandoobject, facebook-ads-api

Maybe this is a silly question, but I'm working on a project that wants me to [generate some JSON](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adcreative/#adtypes) that looks like this:

```
{'action.type':'post', 'application':APP_ID}
```

In C#, I'm trying to create this "action.type" attribute, with the value of "post". How would I do that? Here's how I've typlically been creating stuff like:

```
dynamic ActionSpec = new ExpandoObject();
ActionSpec.SomeParam = "something";
ActionSpec.id = 12345;
```

I can't go "ActionSpec.action.type", because that will not output the desired "action.type".
Does this make sense?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could *try* populating it via the dictionary:

```
IDictionary<string, object> expandoDictionary = ActionSpec;
expandoDictionary["action.type"] = "post";
```

However, I wouldn't be at all surprised if it rejected that as an invalid identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
JObject jObj = new JObject();

jObj["action.type"] = "post";
jObj["application"] = "APP_ID";

var json = jObj.ToString();
```